# Vertical align text with a link inside a div block

Tags: html, css

Can't center text vertically with a link, this is my html code:

```
<div style="background: #F7C0B9;width: 645px;height: 70px;margin: 0 auto;outline: 1px solid #FFF;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;line-height: 70px;">
    <p style="">
        Text <br />
        <a href="#">
            Link
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I've tried to specify vertical align, to p tag, also tried line-height, but no success, link still is out of position.

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/85q6wqjx/

Comment: Which browser are you using, seems fine in Chrome as I can see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can realize this layout as follows.

First, set `display: inline-block` to the `p`, that way you can align it with
the baseline of the content box.

Second, you need to reset the `line-height` within `p` to some reasonable 
value to get the line spacing to look right.

Third, apply `vertical-align: middle` to the `p` element for it to have the
desired effect.

This approach will work with any number of text lines, as demonstrated.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/1mwkbr0q/

```css
.panel {
    background:#F7C0B9;
    width:645px;
    height:170px;
    margin:0 auto;
    outline:1px solid #FFF;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 170px;
}
.panel p {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    line-height: 1.25;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <p>Text<br /> <a href="#">Link<br>a 3rd line for example</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please remove `<br>` tag you will get what you want

and update your code snippet with

```
 <div style="background:#F7C0B9;width:645px;height:70px;margin:0 auto;outline:1px solid #FFF;text-align: center;padding: 17px 0;box-sizing: border-box;">
            <p style="margin: 0;">Text</p>
             <a href="#">Link</a>

        </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/85q6wqjx/10/

Comment: Link must be on new line.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the Link under the text but still both in middle:

```
<div style="background:#F7C0B9;width:645px;height:70px;margin:0 auto;outline:1px solid #FFF;text-align:center;vertical-align: middle;">
  <p style="display:inline-block;">
    Text <br />
      <a href="#">
        Link
      </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/85q6wqjx/2/)

Your `line-height` was pushing it outside the `div` and the `p` being a block element was stopping it from going under. You needed to make `p` an `inline-block` element.

---

If you want them both on the same line, remove `<br>` from the html.

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/85q6wqjx/3/)

`br` is a line break and `line-height` effects by that.

Comment: Please note that this doesn't work if you add more lines: http://jsfiddle.net/85q6wqjx/6/

Comment: OP didn't state this had to work for more than one line. Plus if OP removes the set height it would work. @Sirence

Comment: @Sirence http://jsfiddle.net/85q6wqjx/7/ (Put the text in the `p`! You didn't in your fiddle!)

Answer (score 0):

Just add following code to your css file

```
a {
    margin-top: -8%;
    display: block;
}
```

give class/id name to anchor tag if you want to add style particular anchor tag